# APNS Push notifications are not working if app is installing from iTunes and working if app is running from Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, push-notification

i have used app with ios8.0 SDK and created explicit app id which is enabled push notifications for development environment

I have create provision profile for explicit app id and added profile to Xcode and run the app , then device token is generating, by using NWpusher i have tested notifications. notifications are working fire.

If we build the app and created ipa and installing that ipa on same device, generating different device token, and by using that device token in NWpusher app notifications are not working

Here i have used only developer environment for notifications

Comment: did you see my answer? does it help? @Afsara

Comment: Yes i got it, but my server is not supporting production environment need to work on it. Mean while we can't use Sandbox environment for ipa? will ipa file won't support sandbox environment ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to repeat the exact same procedure that you undertook for the development certificate and testing in Xcode, once again only now for the production environment.

Getting push notifications to work can be a real pain, thus it is important to take a structured approach. Your issue is actually quite common, people tend to think that once they got push running in dev mode, it'll work in production mode immediately. This is not the case.

I recommend you to go through [Ray Wenderlich's Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1) on Push and take it step by step. They are demonstrating the case with a dev certificate as well, but the in the end they state the following (and this part is very often overread, they should point it out more clearly):

> When you are ready to release your app, repeat this process for the
>   production certificate. The steps are the same.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate certificate and environment for distribution to work